# nginx didn't cache page

Tags: nginx, cache

I have FreeBSD server with nginx as reverse proxy.

When I test it with ab util, I see some strange things, such as:

1. Internal pages aren't cached.
2. Main page is cached, but sometimes the non-cached version is returned.

I don't know where I've made a mistake. Please, help.

Here's part of the config:

```
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {

    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         200;

    proxy_buffer_size          4m;
    proxy_buffers              24 1m;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    8m;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 4m;

    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=all:512m;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    aio sendfile;
    directio 1M;
    output_buffers 64 256k;


    server {
        listen < hidden >;
        server_name < hidden >;

        error_page 412 = @fallback;

        proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri";
        proxy_cache_valid 404 5m;
        proxy_cache_valid 500 501 502 503 504 1m;
        proxy_cache_valid any 10m;
        proxy_cache_use_stale http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_logined;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_logined;

        location / {
            if ($cookie_logined) { return 412; }
            proxy_cache all;

            proxy_pass < hidden >;
            proxy_redirect < hidden > /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not fully understand how the cache.
Key parameters of the cache, such as:

- proxy_cache_key
- proxy_cache_lock
- proxy_cache_lock_timeout
- proxy_cache_methods
- proxy_cache_bypass
- proxy_cache_valid

I think that the default values ​​give this effect.
Read [this part of the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key).